# paypal form not sending data properly

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to submit the following paypal form through a hosted-payment system. however, it does not seem to be passing through any of the variables apart from the price.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong:

```
<form action='https://securepayments.paypal.com/cgi-bin/acquiringweb' method='post'  target='hss_iframe' id='PayPalForm' name='PayPalForm'>
  <input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_hosted-payment' />
  <input type='hidden' name='charset' value='utf-8' />
  <input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='GBP' />
  <input type='hidden' name='business' value='seller@email.com' />
  <input type='hidden' name='paymentaction' value='sale' />
  <input type='hidden' name='template' value='TemplateD' />
  <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://yoursite.com/groupon-success.php' />
  <input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='http://yoursite.com/paypal-groupon-  ipn.php' />
  <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='Item name' />
  <input type='hidden' name='item_number' value='4' />
  <input type='hidden' name='subtotal' value='0.01' />
  <input type='hidden' name='custom' value='41' />
  <input type='hidden' name='address_override' value='true' />
  <input type='hidden' name='first_name' value='Jack' />
  <input type='hidden' name='last_name' value='Jones' />
  <input type='hidden' name='address1' value='address1' />
  <input type='hidden' name='city' value='Manchester' />
  <input type='hidden' name='zip' value='M20 1AA' />
  <input type='hidden' name='country' value='UK' />
  <input type='hidden' name='billing_first_name' value='Jack' />
  <input type='hidden' name='billing_last_name' value='Jones' />
  <input type='hidden' name='billing_address1' value='address1' />
  <input type='hidden' name='billing_city' value='Manchester' />
  <input type='hidden' name='billing_zip' value='M20 1AA' />
  <input type='hidden' name='billing_country' value='UK' />
</form>
```

it is then been passed to an iframe which seems to work fine using:

```
<iframe width="100%" scrolling="no" height="580px" frameborder="no" name="hss_iframe" style="float:right;"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#PayPalForm").submit();
});
</script>
```

Can anyone help with why this data does not seem to pass anything through

--------------- EDIT

Changed cmd to _xclick and passes through fine, so obviously an issue with _hosted-payment

Can anyone give any ideas

Answer (score 0):

If by "however, it does not seem to be passing through any of the variables", you mean it doesn't display the item name / item number: that's correct. Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution doesn't currently support item details. You should remove these parameters as they're not in use for this product.

In addition, the billing/shipping address **will** be used, but you won't be able to modify them if you're using templateD.

Comment: thanks for this, does it support the custom field? thats the one i really need apart from the shipping etc.

Comment: It does, yes. 'custom' will be returned via IPN and will also be available in the GetTransactionDetails API response (if you happen to use it).

Comment: thanks robert, while i have you, i am trying to update through IPN and not working mysql_query("UPDATE `back_orders` SET `fname`='$first_name', `lname`='$last_name', `add1`='$address_street',  `city`='$address_city', `postcode`='$address_zip', `country`='$address_country', `email`='$payer_email', `paid`='$mc_gross', `date`='$date' WHERE `order_id`='$orderno.'");
} is this a known bug?

Comment: Err, no, because that's not PayPal code, so I don't see how it could be a bug on their end. :-) -- But feel free to file a new question with your full IPN code included